# How to get combo box to say one thing but put in something else?

Tags: java, database

So I have a Combo box setup with some text, but I would like the text to say one thing when I get the value on the text I want it to put in a SQL statement I have written

Code example

```
      Label querydroplabel = new Label("Select from drop down");
      ComboBox<String> querydrop = new ComboBox<>();
      querydrop.getItems().addAll(
              "Sort cities by population / acending",
              "Sort cities by population / descending",
              "Sort cities by name",
              "Get total population",
              "Get AVG population",
              "Get Highest population",
              "Get Lowest population");
      querydrop.setOnAction(event ->
      {
          queryTextArea.setText(querydrop.getValue());
      });
```

So when I select say the first one (Sort cities by population / ascending)
I want to get value but I want that value to be `SELECT cityname FROM City ORDER BY population ASC`

Comment: Create a custom Object with two properties to add to the model. One property will be disploayed in the combo box and the other will be used in your SQL. See: [Combo Box With Hidden Data](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/) for an example of this approach. Also, your code indicates you are using AWT components. You should be using Swing components. Swing components start with "J". That is JLabel, JComboBox etc.

Comment: AWT had Choice component, while `ComboBox` is implemented in JavaFX

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, you may use an enum:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public enum ComboSQL {
    SORT_CITY_POPULATION_ASC(
        "Sort cities by population / ascending",
        "SELECT cityname FROM City ORDER BY population ASC"),
    SORT_CITY_POPULATION_DESC(
        "Sort cities by population / descending",
        "SELECT cityname FROM City ORDER BY population DESC"),
    SORT_CITY_NAME        ("Sort cities by name",    "SELECT cityname FROM City ORDER BY cityname"),
    GET_TOTAL_POPULATION  ("Get total population",   "SELECT SUM(population) FROM City"),
    GET_AVERAGE_POPULATION("Get AVG population",     "SELECT AVG(population) FROM City"),
    GET_HIGHEST_POPULATION("Get Highest population", "SELECT MAX(population) FROM City"),
    GET_LOWEST_POPULATION ("Get Lowest population",  "SELECT MIN(population) FROM City");

    private String label;
    private String sql;

    private ComboSQL(String label, String sql) {
        this.label = label;
        this.sql = sql;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }

    public String getSQL() {
        return this.sql;
    }

    public static ComboSQL getByLabel(String label) {
        return Arrays.stream(ComboSQL.values())
                .filter(e -> e.getLabel().equals(label))
                .findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to populate combo using labels and then map selected element of the combo to the enum

```
      querydrop.getItems().addAll(
          Arrays.stream(ComboSQL.values())
              .map(ComboSQL::getLabel)
              .collect(Collectors.toList())
      );
      // ...
      querydrop.setOnAction(event ->
      {          
          queryTextArea.setText(ComboSQL.getByLabel(querydrop.getValue()).getSQL());
      });
```

It is also possible to find an SQL by the index:

```
querydrop.setOnAction(event ->
      {          
          int selectedIndex = querydrop.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
          if (selectedIndex > -1) {
              ComboSQL combo = ComboSQL.values()[selectedIndex];
              queryTextArea.setText(combo.getSQL());
          }
      });
```

Comment: I tried and ran into some issues. Is there any possible way to add something simple like an action event if-else statement ......like .....

`querydrop.setOnAction(event -> 
{ if (querydrop.equals("Sort cities by population / acending")){ queryTextArea.setText("Test"); } else {queryTextArea.setText("Test");}});`

Comment: You can surely use `if-else` statement, if you'd like, just set different values to text area,  Could you specify which issues you encountered with the offred approach, thanks!

Comment: @PROJ3CT2501, I updated the method `getByLabel` in ComboSQL - it should be fine now

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a relatively simple solution would be to pull the required SQL String from a String[] Array based on the index value of the selected item within the Combo-Box, for example:

```
/* You can fill this array from a section in a text file or
   from a database table of SQL Strings, or whatever...   */
String[] sqlByComboIndex = {"SELECT cityname FROM City ORDER BY population ASC;",  
                            "SELECT cityname FROM City ORDER BY population DESC;",
                            "SELECT cityname FROM City ORDER BY name ASC;",
                            "SELECT SUM(population) FROM City;",
                            "SELECT AVG(population) FROM City;",
                            "SELECT cityname, MAX(population) AS HighestPopulation FROM City GROUP BY cityname ORDERED BY cityname;",
                            "SELECT cityname, MIN(population) AS LowestPopulation FROM City GROUP BY cityname ORDERED BY cityname;"
                            };
int comboIndex = jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();
String sqlString = null;
if (comboIndex >= 0) {
    sqlString = sqlByComboIndex[comboIndex];
}
```

I give no guarantees on the queries. :)